# Acceder a otra máquina utilizando Traefik 2

Tags: docker, traefik, traefik2, proxmox

Tengo actualmente montado docker en una máquina debian. Para poder acceder a los distintos servicios tengo Traefik 2 funcionando como reverse proxy.

El problema que se me plantea es que necesito acceder desde fuera de mi red a otras máquinas fuera de docker pero no tengo claro cómo configurarlo en Traefik 2. Mi máquina debian tiene como IP 10.10.10.3 y necesito acceder a otras máquinas (10.10.10.3:8088, 10.10.10.7, 10.10.10.10, etc) pero no lo consigo.

Utilizo un fichero en traefik (rules.yml) donde creía que había añadir esto, pero algo estoy pasando por alto que no funciona. Me tira un error 404 Page Not Found al intentar acceder mediante omv.dominio.eu

Tal y como tengo actualmente el fichero rules.yml consigo acceder a omv.dominio.eu (sin certificado eso si) pero para acceder a la máquina proxmox (10.10.10.7:8006 / pve.dominio.eu) obtengo un mensaje "Bad gateway".

Esto es lo que obtengo con wget:

```
root@debian:~# wget https://pve.dominio.eu
--2020-04-27 20:06:04--  https://pve.dominio.eu/
Resolving pve.dominio.eu (pve.dominio.eu)... 9X.123.45.135
Connecting to pve.dominio.eu (pve.dominio.eu)|9X.123.45.135|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of 'pve.dominio.eu' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'pve.dominio.eu' doesn't have a known issuer.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname 'pve.dominio.eu'
```

Este es el contenido del ese fichero rules:

```
http:
  routers:
    router0:
      rule: Host(`omv.dominio.eu`)
     # entryPoints:
     # - http
     # middlewares:
     # - https-redirect
      service: omv
      # will terminate the TLS request
      tls: {}
      #tls:
      #  passthrough: true
    router1:
      rule: Host(`pve.dominio.eu`)
      service: pve
      tls: {}

  services:
    omv:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        scheme: https
        - url: http://10.10.10.3:8088
        passHostHeader: true

    pve:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        scheme: https
        - url: http://10.10.10.7:8006
        passHostHeader: true


      middlewares:
        https-redirect:
          redirectScheme:
            scheme: https

        default-headers:
          headers:
            frameDeny: true
            sslRedirect: true
            browserXssFilter: true
            contentTypeNosniff: true
            forceSTSHeader: true
            stsIncludeSubdomains: true
            stsPreload: true

        default-whitelist:
          ipWhiteList:
            sourceRange:
            - "10.0.0.0/24"
            - "192.168.0.0/16"
            - "172.0.0.0/8"

        secured:
          chain:
            middlewares:
            - default-whitelist
            - default-headers
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.
Gracias.

Añado información: He conseguido acceder a la máquina 10.10.10.3:8088 (sin TSL eso si pero no me preocupa mucho). En cambio necesito acceder a otra máquina con Proxmox con IP 10.10.10.7:8006 y obtengo el mensaje "Bad gateway" al intentar acceder desde fuera de la red: Edito mi pregunta con más datos.

Comment: Añado información:

He conseguido acceder a la máquina 10.10.10.3:8088 (sin TSL eso si pero no me preocupa mucho). En cambio necesito acceder a otra máquina con Proxmox con IP 10.10.10.7:8006 y obtengo el mensaje "Bad gateway" al intentar acceder desde fuera de la red:

Edito mi pregunta con más datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien,

Después de un tiempo de pruebas publico aquí la solución que encontré.

Lo primero es hacer referencia al fichero "config.yml" desde el fichero "traefik.yml" y añadirlo como *file provider*:

```
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml
```

A continuación, en el fichero config.yml, hay que añadir proxmox como un servicio TCP y no como HTTP:

```
tcp:
  routers:
    proxmox-tcp:
      entryPoints:
        - https
      rule: "HostSNI(`pve.dominio.com`)"
      service: proxmox-svc
      tls:
        passthrough: true

  services:
    proxmox-svc:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - address: '10.10.10.7:8006'
```

Quedando mi fichero config.yml así:

```
http:
  middlewares:
    https-redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https

    default-headers:
      headers:
        frameDeny: true
        sslRedirect: true
        browserXssFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsPreload: true

    default-whitelist:
      ipWhiteList:
        sourceRange:
        - "10.0.0.0/24"
        - "192.168.0.0/16"
        - "172.0.0.0/8"

    secured:
      chain:
        middlewares:
          - default-whitelist
          - default-headers

## DYNAMIC CONFIGURATION
tcp:
  routers:
    proxmox-tcp:
      entryPoints:
        - https
      rule: "HostSNI(`pve.dominio.com`)"
      service: proxmox-svc
      tls:
        passthrough: true

  services:
    proxmox-svc:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - address: '10.10.10.7:8006'
```

Con esto conseguimos acceder desde fuera de nuestra red. Aunque nos dirá que el certificado no es válido podemos al menos acceder.

Saludos.